# Getting Error 400 Bad Request while trying to ENcrypt a string using RSA Public Key

Tags: javascript, web-services, wcf, encryption, cryptography

I have created a java-script  web client for a WCF service hosted on my machine. I am trying to implement RSA Encryption on service side and decryption on client side.

To achieve RSA I am generating a public  key and then passing it to the service method for Encryption using that key.

The key gets passed fine but the **Encryption method sends a 400 BAD REQUEST ERROR** while Encrypting. I am not bale to figure out how to fix this error. Here is code for generating public key.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnSend").click(function () {
                    debugger;
                    jQuery.support.cors = true;

                    var doOaepPadding = true;
                    var rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    _privateKey = rsa.ToXmlString(true);
                    _publicKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false);
```

Here is the code I am using for encryption on the service side

```
public static string Encrypt(string data)
    {
        var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       rsa.FromXmlString(_publicKey);
        var dataToEncrypt = _encoder.GetBytes(data);
        var encryptedByteArray = rsa.Encrypt(dataToEncrypt, false).ToArray();
        var length = encryptedByteArray.Count();
        var item = 0;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var x in encryptedByteArray)
        {
            item++;
            sb.Append(x);

            if (item < length)
                sb.Append(",");
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Any suggestions that can help me to understand what is going wrong with this Encryption Method would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why are you mixing C# and JavaScript code?

Comment: @ Artjom B: well my service is in C# and I want to develop a javascript client mainly the reason being js is client side and light weight..